# Find the last occurence of a string being a certain length

Tags: ruby

I know there is a method to find the largest string in an array

```
def longest_word(string_of_words)
  x = string_of_words.split(" ").max_by(&:length)
end
```

However, if there are multiple words with the longest length, how do i return the last instance of the word with the longest length? Is there a method and do I use indexing?

Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if we took advantage of `reverse`?

```
"asd qweewe lol qwerty df qwsazx".split.reverse_each.max_by(&:length)
=> "qwsazx"
```

Comment: I am slightly confused how the 'reverse' method would find the last instance of the word with the longest length?

Comment: `max_by` finds that. But the first one. So, first, we reverse the array

Answer (score 2):

Simply [reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse) your words array before applying `max_by`.

The first longest word from the reversed array will be the last one in your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inject` which will replace the maximum only if (via `<=`) it's matched or improved upon. By default `inject` takes the first element of its receiver.

```
str.split.inject { |m,s| m.size <= s.size ?  s : m }
```

Answer (score 1):

can do this way also:

```
 > "asd qweewe lol qwerty df qwsazx".split.sort_by(&:length).last
 #=> "qwsazx"
```

**Note:** You can `split` words and `sort` by `length` in **ascending**(default) order and take the `last` word

Comment: Also, this works because `sort_by` is a stable sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_by.with_index{|e, i| [e, i]}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, try with the string `"asd qweewe lol qwerty df qwsazx hellos"`.

Comment: In order to make your answer feasible for this site, you better _explain_ your solution, instead of just posting code.

Comment: I believe sawa meant to replace `max_by(&:length)` in the OP's code with `max_by.with_index{|e, i| [e.length, i]}`. (sawa note the omission.) That way, should two words have the same length, the tie goes to the one with the greater index. (See the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how Ruby orders arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert the string to an array.

```
def longest_word(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/).
      each_with_object('') {|s,longest| longest.replace(s) if s.size >= longest.size}
end

longest_word "Many dogs love to swim in the sea"
  #=> "swim"
```

Two points.

- I've used [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to create an enumerator that will feed words to [Enumerable.#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). The string argument is not modified. This is an usual use of `gsub` that I've been able to use to advantage in several situations.
- Within the block it's necessary to use `longest.replace(s)` rather than `longest = s`. That's because `each_with_object` returns the originally given object (usually modified by the block), but does not update that object on each iteration. `longest = s` merely returns `s` (is equivalent to just `s`) but does not alter the value of the block variable. By contrast, `longest.replace(s)` modifies the original object.

With regard to the second of these two points, it is interesting to contrast the use of `each_with_object` with [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

```
  str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/).
      reduce('') {|longest,s| s.size >= longest.size ? s : longest }
    #=> "swim"
```